# Pandas DataFrame: Add new column with calculated values based on previous row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame df:

```
            name          rating    val1     val2        val3
<DATE>                                                 
2020-10-16  cool_name      23.0  1.700079  1.515385  0.184694
2020-10-19  cool_name      -3.0  1.230071  1.289615 -0.059545
2020-10-20  cool_name     -11.0  0.007064  0.675135 -0.668071
2020-10-21  cool_name     -21.0 -2.093643 -0.408622 -1.685021
2020-10-22  cool_name      -5.0 -2.384278 -0.638191 -1.746087
```

How can I add a new column called "calculated" which is calculated this way:

```
df['calculated'] = df['calculated'(previous day)] + df['val3'(current day)]
```

If I try to do it this way,  I'll receive a key error (I am not even sure if it is shift(1) or shift(-1)):

```
df['calculated'] = df['calculated'].shift() + df['val3']
```

I think this is due to the fact that the first row doesn't have a previous row with "calculated" . Howerver, I don't know how to solve this problems.

I tried various solutions and searched for answers, but unfortunately I'm stuck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: where is 'calculated' column? that you are shifting?

Comment: It doesn't exist yet. 'calculated' is a new column which should be calculated based on a previous value and a today's value (see second part of the question)

Comment: you want to add df['val3'] to the all columns of the previous day?

Comment: I want to add a new column called 'calculated'. Its value should be: Last_row_value(calculated) + current_row_value(val3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is the same as accumulation of the value of `val3` everyday (probably thinking in Excel style of formula).  As such, you can try using [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), as follows:

```
df['calculated'] = df['val3'].cumsum()
```

You got the error because when you are going to define the column `calculated`, it is derived also from column values of `calculated` which is yet to be defined. Hence, the error.

You can use the code above to get the same result directly without relying on a column not yet defined.

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                 name  rating      val1      val2      val3  calculated
2020-10-16  cool_name    23.0  1.700079  1.515385  0.184694    0.184694
2020-10-19  cool_name    -3.0  1.230071  1.289615 -0.059545    0.125149
2020-10-20  cool_name   -11.0  0.007064  0.675135 -0.668071   -0.542922
2020-10-21  cool_name   -21.0 -2.093643 -0.408622 -1.685021   -2.227943
2020-10-22  cool_name    -5.0 -2.384278 -0.638191 -1.746087   -3.974030
```

Comment: You are absolutely right about my formula, and it is funny that I couldn't see that. Your answer is very simple and easy to understand, which is why I will go with this one. Thanks!